# My function only works with integer numbers

Tags: excel, vba, function, math

I found and modified this code so that I have a mathematical formula in N24 of "Funcio" sheet. The goal is to easily make f(x)-x data tables, and at the same time, to be able to modify the formula in N24 to make the whole workbook recalculate all the tables with the new f(x)

```
Function EvalForx2(ByVal X2 As Long) As Double
x = CDec(X2)
strEquation = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Funcio").Range("N24").Value
EvalForx2 = Evaluate(Replace(strEquation, "x", CStr(x), 1, -1, vbTextCompare))
End Function
```

This works fine, but only if my input variable X2 is an integer. If I add any decimals it gives back the value of the function at the closest integer. The picture below shows what I mean:

[image: Picture]

I dont know much of VBA (which means close to nothing) and I can't figure out my mistake, any help is appreciated

Comment: Try using `ByVal X2 As Double`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried that (as I replied to @pᴇʜ) and the f(x) values that had a non-integer x are now displaying ¡#VALUE! instead of being rounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you defined `X2 As Long` and `Long` is a long `Integer`, so it cannot have decimals. If you write a `9.75` into a variable of type `Long` it will automatically round into `10`.

You need to define your input variable `X2 As Double` which can contain decimal numbers with *double* precision.

```
Function EvalForx2(ByVal X2 As Double) As Double
```

Additionally if you are on a non-english Excel you need to translate `,` into `.` because `Evaluate` only takes `.` as decimal separator:

```
Function EvalForx2(ByVal x As Double) As Double

    Dim strEquation As String
    strEquation = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Funcio").Range("N24").Value
    
    EvalForx2 = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(strEquation, "x", CStr(x), 1, -1, vbTextCompare), ",", "."))

End Function
```

---

Note that you can improve your function like this:

```
Function EvalForx2(ByVal x As Double, ByVal FunctionString As String) As Double
   
    EvalForx2 = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(FunctionString, "x", CStr(x), 1, -1, vbTextCompare), ",", "."))

End Function
```

And then run it like

```
=EvalForx2(A1, Funcio!$N$24)
```

This way you can point your formula to any cell where a function string is written, without changing the code.

Another big advantage is, that when ever the function string in the cell `Funcio!$N$24` is changed this formula automatically re-calculates because the function now depends on that cell. Your first function does not automatically re-calculate the new function string!

Comment: First, thanks for answer. I've tried to change that and now the cells which are not integer have #¡VALUE! in them

Comment: @sam The issue is probably your formula `sin(x)-x^2/10` where a `-9` turns into `sin(-9)--9^2/10`. You need brackets there: Try `sin(x)-((x)^2/10)`

Comment: @sam The issue is that your Excel uses `,` as decimal separator but the `Evaluate` function needs a `.` as decimal separator. So you need to replace all `,` see my edited answer.

Comment: The translation defintely made it work, thank you! :)

Comment: @Sam Check my edit. If you improve your function you can point it easily to any cell where a function string is written, so you don't need to change the address in the code.

Comment: In fact, the first code you wrote is the one I found here at first haha. I do it this way (With the N24 in the code) because that page is the "input" one, the page where the user types the equation and changes it for the whole workbook. If I ask the user to point at the string formula, it's more "complex". My next step is to put a button in each page which allows the user to change the function in the first sheet directly with an Inputbox. Its not such an advantage, but will make it more comfy to use. Thanks for your suggestion anyway, I really appreciate it!!